# Merging PDFs via php... the way the PDF is created is causing errors

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, fpdf

So we have tried every possible solution to a problem we are having.
We have an online form that has many uploads file options. On submission, the form data is manipulated on the back end and **creates a pdf using phpToPDF**. Works great. We then grab all the file uploads (they have to be PDFs) and we then use another **library (libmergepdf) to merge that with our own created PDFs**. We have found this only works on PDFs that are of certain version types. We scrapped that for **fpdf and fpdi libraries and they merged only about 80% of the time properly**. We were finding that not all PDFs are created equal and those created via the "Save as PDF" in Word were not the same as those sent to the print server or even from a Mac. It wasn't an Acorbat version issue but the way it was created. 
We have found no other options at this point but to use ImageMagick to break all the PDFs to images and then reassemble as one PDF. 
Has anyone had any success with either libmergepdf or fpdi working on ALL PDFs? This seems like it shouldn't be this difficult but I have been around stack too many times and can't seem to find a solution. Breaking into images and recompiling seems unneeded!

Comment: I've had some success using [`pdftk`](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/) in the past. It's not a PHP library but a shell command you can probably invoke from PHP.

Comment: `Cairo` is also a good option. Best thing is that `ImageMagick` can be used with `Cairo`.

Comment: We ended up going with ImageMagick and just converted all PDFs to PDF (which seems like an unneeded step but it converts all the PDFs to one type). ImageMagick was the only thing we could find that really didnt care what created the PDF because it treats it like an image. Lost a bit of quality but did the job,

Answer (score 0):

We offer the [FPDI PDF-Parser](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi-pdf-parser/details/) (not free!) in case you want to process PDF documents with a compressed cross-reference and object streams. As you didn't quote any error message I can only guess that this is the issue you're experiencing.

It also supports reading of some corrupted PDF files.

If you are missing things like links or bookmark outlines in the resulting PDFs you may check out the [SetaPDF-Merger](https://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-merger/details/) component, which concatenates PDF documents on a much lower level.